# Laravel dispatch doesn't create entry in jobs table

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel 7 website that has to dispatch some jobs when the user access some pages. On the controller I have the following line:

```php
TheJob::dispatch()->delay(now()->addMinutes(1));
```

This way it should create an entry to the `jobs` table before executing the job, but when running it either on tinker or accessing the page itself, no entry is created on the `jobs` table and the job is not executed. The table does exist on the database and all settings to connect to the database are correct since the page you have to access requires information from other tables.

The job is also not failling since no entry is created on the `failed_jobs` table, and nothing is logged on `storage/logs`.

I have checked the .env file and `QUEUE_CONNECTION` is set to `database` and also tried `php artisan config:cache` to refresh the config cache, to no success. The `config/queue.php` file has not been changed since its creation.

What could be preventing from a job to be created on the jobs table?

Comment: is the queue running? `php artisan queue:work`

Comment: Yes, the queue is running. But an entry on the jobs should be made anyways right?

Comment: Does the queue pickup the job?

Comment: No the worker doesnt even pickup the job if you just dispatch it directly. But other laravel systems on the same server have their jobs picked up by the workers

Comment: @Lopoi anything in your log file to indicate something is going wrong?

Comment: @party-ring No, log files are clean.

Comment: Any luck? have same problem... the job was working before and now suddenly stopped working

Comment: @M.ImranMamda Unfortunatly I dont have access to the server that had this problem anymore. I belive it was fixed by restarting the machine, but I cant confirm it for you.

Comment: @Lopoi thanks for the hint, I can confirm that restart did actually work. Though I don't really know the reason behind it.